# cx_freeze include css file and image in dash app

Tags: css, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze, plotly-dash

I have some difficulties to apply a css file to my dash app when using cx_freeze. If I run `python app.py` the layout is properly applied, however not if I am executing the `.exe` generated by cx_freeze. Then the default html layout is displayed. The css and the image appear in the same directory where the `.exe` is located.

This is how my setup.py looks like.

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': [
            'cx_Logging', 'idna', 'idna.idnadata'
        ],
        'packages': [
            'asyncio', 'flask', 'jinja2', 'dash', 'plotly', 'waitress'
        ],
        'excludes': ['tkinter'],
        'include_files': [
          'assets/logo.jpg', 'assets/style.css'
        ],
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('server.py',
               base='console',
               targetName='dash_app.exe')
]

setup(
    name='BI_Report',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.0.1',
    description='rig',
    executables=executables,
    options=options
)
```

To load the external files I use a helper function as suggested [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/convert-dash-to-executable-file-exe/14222/30):

```
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)


app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                assets_folder=find_data_file('assets/'))
```

I am using:

```
Python 3.7.6
dash 1.9.1
cx-freeze 6.1
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Same problem here, finally solved?

Comment: Same issue here. Any updates yet?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the building options slightly

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files': ['assets/'],
    }
 }
```

I successfully found the assets using

```
app = Dash(__name__, assets_folder=os.getcwd()+'/assets/')
```

Note that this solution copies the assets folder twice when building.